# Regular Expressions in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm trying to use regular expressions within Google Sheets. Given that the environment is within GSheets some functionality seems to be missing or, potentially just different.

I would like to use a regexmatch function that returns true if the range in question contains any of the following strings:

"string1"
"string2"
"string3"

I tried `=regexmatch(range,"([Ss]tring1|[[Ss]tring2|[Ss]tring3)"`

This works.

But my developer colleague said he would usually just end the expression `/i` to say "Be case insensitive"

```
=regexmatch(range,"/(String1|String2|String3)/i"
```

But since Gsheets does not use "/" to open a regular expression, is there another way to tell the function to ignore case?

Also, is there a way to negate the expression? That is, instead of:

```
=NOT(regexmatch(range,"([Ss]tring1|[[Ss]tring2|[Ss]tring3)")
```

Can you do something like

```
=regexmatch(range,"!=([Ss]tring1|[[Ss]tring2|[Ss]tring3)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try wrapping your range with the "lower" function, so compares the values as if they are all lower case regardless of whether they really are or not.

```
=REGEXMATCH(lower(range),"string1|string2|string3")
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there another way to tell the function to ignore case?

Please try:

```
=regexmatch(range,"(?i)string1|string2|string3")
```

Comment: Tried it with no success. Here is the full formula I tried (does not work):
=iferror(sum(filter(indirect($AD$5),region1=$AD$4,industry=$A11,quarter=C$9,not(REGEXMATCH(bu,"(?i)apples|pears|bananas)")))),0)
Whereas this does work:
iferror(sum(filter(indirect($AD$5),region1=$AD$4,industry=$A11,quarter=C$9,not(REGEXMATCH(bu,"[Aa]pples|[Pp]ears|[Bb]ananas)")))),0)
I prefer your syntax but can't seem to get it. What you think?